# Is there a performance penalty associated with calling a function within a @try block?

Tags: objective-c

Would this cause a performance penalty, compared to calling `blabla` without the try block?

```
-(void)bla{
    @try{
        [self blabla];
    }
    @catch (NSException *e) {
        // Do nothing
    }
}
```

Comment: I've seen this asked here for C and C++.  Although I'm not positive the answer is the same, I'm betting it is.  Anyway, you ought to check out the "compared to what" threads in the answers for both of those languages.  For example, here's one:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16784601/does-try-catch-block-decrease-performance

Comment: There is possibly some minor loss of compiler optimization, but probably nothing else.  (And "Objective-C compiler optimization" is something of an oxymoron anyway.)

Comment: Not much of a problem since we don't throw exceptions that often in Objective-C :)

Comment: @Gavin ... and we can't catch them reliably.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

from [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Exceptions/Articles/Exceptions64Bit.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009044-SW1)

> Zero-Cost @try Blocks
>
> 64-bit processes that enter a zero-cost @try block incur no
>   performance penalty. This is unlike the mechanism for 32-bit
>   processes, which calls setjmp() and performs additional “bookkeeping”.
>   However, throwing an exception is much more expensive in 64-bit
>   executables. For best performance in 64-bit, you should throw
>   exceptions only when absolutely necessary.

so no overhead for **64-bit** processes

Comment: It's important to notice that this is true for Mac OS X only. On iOS the implementation always was like the 64 Bit Mac architecture.

Answer (score 4):

You might be interested in this blog here: [LLVM PROJECT BLOG](http://blog.llvm.org/2013/10/new-libunwind-implementation-in-libcabi.html)

That is, on Intel and since Okt. 2013, on ARM too, C++ exceptions are now "zero-cost".

The Objective-C exceptions are realized in terms of this implementation.

However, the need for an unwinder will disable a few optimization opportunities, so that code which requires to handle exceptions might be less optimal optimized that when no exceptions have to be handled.

Answer (score 4):

On some platforms, @try/@catch is "zero cost". There is no additional code executed for a try block as long as no exception is thrown. There is extra overhead in the form of exception unwinding data, but that also occupies no real memory until an exception is thrown. These platforms include 64-bit OS X and 64-bit iOS.

On some platforms, merely entering @try incurs some CPU overhead to save registers. These platforms include 32-bit OS X and 32-bit iOS.