# Undecided between using exceptions or reporting error messages

Tags: c++, exception

I'm working on a small project for numerical integration. I've been reading topics like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4506369/when-and-how-should-i-use-exception-handling) and I couldn't decide if I should throw exceptions when the user supplies bad integration limits, requests impossible precision and things like that.

Also, what if a procedure fails to converge for the provided conditions? Should I throw an exception?

Right now what I have are error codes represented in integer variables, which I pass around between many routines, but I'd like to reduce the number of variables the user must declare and whose value they must consult.

I was thinking about a scenario where exceptions are thrown by the library routines in the circumstances I mentioned above and caught by the user. Would that be acceptable? If not, what would be a good approach?

Thanks.

Comment: Exceptions are easier to handle and don't require reading much/any documentation reading by the user. C is a good example. Call a function, do a null check, if null, check an error code. Hopefully you get a meaningful message, otherwise read the docs/Google the error code. Exceptions are a bit more 'automatic' and can have a meaningful error message already included.

Answer (score 1):

While the question is too broad, I will try to give some general guidance, since this is one of the topics I often talk about.

In general, exceptions are useful when something happened which really shouldn't have happened.

I can give a couple of examples. A programmatic error would be one - when a function call contract is broken, I usually advice throwing an exception rather than returning an error.

An unrecoverable error should trigger an exception, however, judging between recoverable error and non-recoverable error is not always possible at the call site. For example, an attempt to open a non-existing file is usually a recoverable error, which warrants a failure code. But sometimes, the file simply must be there, and there is nothing calling code can do when it is not - so the error becomes unrecoverable. In the latter case, calling code might want the file opening function to throw an exception rather than returning a code.

This introduces the whole topic of exception policies - functions are told if they need to throw exception or return errors.

Answer (score 1):

Before C++11 exceptions were avoided in projects where performance mattered (`-fno-exceptions`). Now, it appears that exceptions do not impact performance (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13835817/are-exceptions-in-c-really-slow) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16784601/does-try-catch-block-decrease-performance)), thus there is no reason not to use them.

A paranoid, but old, approach would be: divide your program in two parts, ui and numerical library. UI could be written in any language and use exceptions. Numerical library would be c or c++ and use no exceptions. For instance (win, but doesn't matter), you could have an UI in c# with exceptions that calls an "unsafe" c++ .dll where exceptions are not used.

Alternative to exception is the classic `return -1;`, the caller has to check return value of every call (even with `optional`, caller still has to check for errors). When a serie of nested function calls is executed and an error arise in the deepest function, you would have to propagate the error all the way up: you would have to check for errors in every call you do.

With Exceptions, you use a `try{}` block and that handle errors inside at any call-depth. Code to handle errors appears only once and does not pollute your numerical-library (or whatever you are creating)

Use exceptions!

Comment: I'm more or less convinced that if the integrand provided by the user, say, itself throws an exception, then I should catch that and send back to the user. I'm just not sure about what would be other "exceptional" conditions. For instance, failure to converge would be one? I'm leaned towards what  @Christopher Schneider says on his comment to my OP. I mean, an exception with an informative error message can be better than passing codes around and/or making the user figure what they mean. Your post here encouraged me to do what I was thinking of doing: Safe UI and "unsafe" lib. Ideas?