# Using throw to replace return in C++ non-void functions

Tags: c++, exception

In C++ functions, is it a good practice to replace `return` with `throw`? For example, I have the following code

```
// return indices of two numbers whose sum is equal to target
vector<int> twoSum(vector<int>& nums, int target) {
    for(int i=0; i<nums.size()-1; ++i)
        for(int j=i+1; j<nums.size(); ++j)
        {
            if(nums[i] + nums[j] == target) return vector<int>{i, j};
        }
    // return vector<int>{};
    throw "no solution";
}
```

The code above compiles with my GCC 7.2.

Comment: It really just depends on if finding a result is an exceptional situation or not and on how you want your function to behave.

Comment: Good practice,maybe.  `std::optional` is my preferred solution if no result isn't exceptional.

Comment: Exceptions are for exceptional situations.  So it depends on your function.  If your function is always expected to return a result, then throwing would make sense.  Otherwise, if "nothing found" is a valid result, then you are better off with something like `std::optional`.

Comment: I really doubt, this would be a good idea in any language, or paradigm

Comment: It will certainly be *slower*.

Comment: Is this really an exceptional case? If there was nothing to do then no results (i.e., an empty `vector`) conveys that. This is completely different than an internal failure that caused computing the results to fail.

Comment: Note that if what you are *actually doing* is replacing a `return` with a `throw` in the sense that you want to return a result via `throw`, then it's a very bad idea. This is not what you are doing here. `throw` is being used to signal a failure which is what it's designed for.

Comment: In c++ I would argue this is bad practice. It's good (or at least acceptable and not unusual) in python, but not for this problem where "None" is a better answer. On an unrelated note, twoSum exists to demonstrate why nested for loops are often a bad solution. There is an O(n) solution which twoSum is basically tailor made to demonstrate.

Comment: Changing your method signature to be more helpful to anyone that calls it. E.g. `bool twoSum( const vector<int>& nums, const int target, int& match1, int& match2 )` makes you think differently about needing to throw at all.

Comment: As a sidenote, never throw strings or string literals. Use `std::logic_error`, `std::runtime_error` or derive from them.

Comment: @dr_g: Let's avoid error codes, please.

Comment: Is there a specific reason for returning a `std::vector` instead of a `std::optional<std::pair<std::size_t, std::size_t>>`? A `std::vector` with either 0 or 2 elements seems very wasteful to me; the memory allocation is overkill, there's no guarantee that it's only 0 or 2, etc...

Comment: Throwing is definitely **not** a *replacement* to returning - they do *completely* different things. Even if you can mimic a `return` using a `throw` they are a lot slower and it would lead to awkward logic.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The concepts of this answer are taken from the C++ Programming language by  Bjarne Stroustrup.

### SHORT ANSWER

Yes, exception-throwing can be used as returning value method. An example is the following for a binary tree search function:

```
void fnd(Tree∗ p, const string& s)
{
    if (s == p−>str) throw p; // found s
    if (p−>left) fnd(p−>left,s);
    if (p−>right) fnd(p−>right,s);
}


Tree∗ find(Tree∗ p, const string& s)
{
    try {
       fnd(p,s);
    }
    catch (Tree∗ q) {
        // q->str==s
        return q;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

However, it should be avoided because:

- they allow you to separate error code from "ordinary code" making your program much more readable, comprehensible and manageable. If you use them as return method, this does not hold anymore.
- there might be inefficiencies because exception implementations rely on the assumption that they are used as error-handling methods.

Apart from that, there are further limitations:

- exceptions must be of copy-able type
- exceptions can handle only synchronous events
- they should be avoided in a time-critical system
- they should be avoided in large old programs in which resource management is an ad hoc mess (free store is unsystematically managed using naked pointers, news and delete) rather than relying on some systematic scheme such as resource handles (strings vectors).

### Longer answer

An exception is an object thrown to represent the occurrence of an error. It can be of any type that can be copied but it is strongly recommended to use only user-defined types specifically defined for that purpose. Exceptions allow the programmer to explicitly separate error-handling code from "ordinary code"  making the program more readable.

First of all, exceptions are for managing **synchronous events**, not asynchronous ones. This is one first limitation.

One might think of the exception-handling mechanisms as simply another control structure, an alternative way of returning a value to a caller.

This has some charm but **should be avoided** because it is likely to cause confusion and inefficiencies. Stroustrup suggests:

> When at all possible stick to the "exception handling is an error
>   handling" view. When this is done code is separated into two categories:
>   ordinary code and error handling code. This makes the code more
>   comprehensible. Furthermore, the implementations of the exception
>   mechanisms are optimized based on the assumption that this simple
>   model underlies the use of the exception.

So basically using exceptions to return value should be avoided because

- **exception implementation is optimized assuming they are used for error-handling and not for returning values** hence they might be inefficient for that;
- They allow separating *error code* from *ordinary code* making the code much more readable and comprehensible. **Anything that helps preserve a clear model of what is an error and how it is handled should be treasured**.

There are programs that for practical or historical reasons cannot use exceptions (neither as error handling so even less):

- A time-critical component of an embedded system where operation must be guaranteed to complete in a specified maximum time. In the absence of tools that can accurately estimate the maximum time for an exception to propagate from `throw` to `catch` alternative error handling methods must be used.
- A large old program in which resource management is an ad hoc mess (free store is unsystematically managed using naked pointers, `news` and `delete`) rather than relying on some systematic scheme such as resource handles (`string`s `vector`s).

In the above cases, traditional pre-exception methods are preferred.

Comment: The question is about exception throwing as returning method. This is an example about it

Answer (score 41):

> In C++ functions, is it a good practice to replace return with throw?

Return is not something that can be replaced by a throw *in general*.

In exceptional cases where you have nothing to return, throwing an exception can be a valid way to exit the function.

Whether it is "good practice", and what case is "exceptional" are subjective. For example, for a search function such as yours, it's hardly a surprise that there might not be a solution, and I would argue that throwing would not be appropriate.

There are often other alternatives to throwing. Compare your algorithm with something like `std::string::find` that returns the index of the start of a substring. In case where substring does not exist, it returns a "non-value" `std::string::npos`. You could do the same and decide that the index -1 is returned when a result is not found. There is also a generic way to add non-value representation to a type in cases where none of the existing representations can be reserved for the purpose: `std::optional`.

P.S. A vector is probably not a good choice for returning a pair of numbers. `std::pair` might be better, or a custom class if you have good names for the numbers.

Comment: Well, I've seen a small codebase once with void functions that returned results by throwing them, and `try-catch` was used as a sort of pattern matching tool. Quite a bizarre design, I have to admit, but it shows how to replace `return` with `throw` *in general*.

Comment: @Joker_vD frankly, I've never seen a function whose all return paths were throws (except "not implemented" style exceptions). But I admit that it would be technically legal C++. So, I've technically lied a bit when I said that returns *cannot* be replaced.

Comment: @Joker_vD: **it's possible, but would perform like crap on "normal" implementations**.  Unless they can optimize away the throw/catch, firing up the stack-unwinding exception dispatch code (which has to go read `.eh_frame` metadata) is vastly more expensive than a `ret` instruction.

Comment: This would be one of the few situations where I'd agree with using `std::pair` - where the two elements are more or less interchangeable.  On a tangent: I disagree with a lot of the places the standard library uses `std::pair` - for example, think how much more readable code would be if you would write `auto result = m_multiplicities.emplace(k, 1); if (!result.inserted) ++(result.location->value);` as opposed to `if (!result.second) ++(result.first->second);`

Comment: of course, returning an error _value_ like `std::string::npos` means the caller might completely forget to check for it and pass it along to some other code, eventually producing nonsense that's hard to trace back to the original cause.  this problem is the entire reason for exceptions (or optional types).

Answer (score 20):

`return` and `throw` have two different purposes and should not be considered interchangeable. Use `return` when you have a valid result to send back to the caller. On the other hand, use `throw` when some exceptional behavior occurs. You can get an idea of how other programmers use `throw` by using functions from the standard library and taking note of when they throw exceptions.

Answer (score 15):

In addition to the other answers, there's also **performance**: Catching an exception incurs a run-time overhead (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16785259/3840951)) compared to an `if` clause.

(Of course, we're talking about microseconds... Whether or not this is relevant depends on your specific use case.)

Comment: Function call/ret takes about a nanosecond on a 3 to 4 GHz CPU, and can overlap with surrounding work.  About 1000x slower sounds plausible.  But remember, microseconds is *thousands* of clock cycles on modern CPUs (during which time they could have executed maybe 1 to 3 instructions per clock, or even more in high-ILP code), and ~ten times longer than even a cache miss that went all the way RAM and stalled out-of-order execution.  try/catch instead of return might not optimize away even after inlining, so you will end up with far more of it than you would `call`/`ret` instructions.

Answer (score 11):

A function should throw an exception when it is unable to meet its postcondition. (Some functions may also throw exceptions when their preconditions are not met; that's a different topic that I won't get into here.) Therefore, if your function *must* return a pair of integers from the vector summing to the given target, then it has no choice but to throw an exception when it can't find one. But if the function's contract allows it to return a value to indicate it was unable to find such a pair, then it should not throw an exception, since it has the ability to fulfill the contract.

In your case:

- You can make your function return an empty vector when it can't find two integers summing to the given target. Then, it never needs to throw an exception.
- Or, you can make your function return `std::optional<std::pair<int, int>>`. It never needs to throw an exception because it can just return an empty optional when it can't find an appropriate pair.
- If, however, you make it return `std::pair<int, int>`, then it should throw an exception because there is no sensible value to return when it can't find an appropriate pair.

Generally, C++ programmers prefer to write functions that don't need to throw exceptions in order to report mere "disappointments", such as search failures, that are easily anticipated and handled locally. The advantages of returning values rather than throwing exceptions are discussed extensively elsewhere so I won't rehash that discussion here.

Thus, declaring "failure" by throwing an exception is usually limited to the following cases:

- The function is a constructor and it's simply not able to establish its class's invariant. It must throw an exception in order to ensure that the calling code doesn't see a broken object.
- An "exceptional" condition arises that should be handled at some higher level than that of the caller. The caller is likely to not know how to recover from the condition. In such cases, the use of the exception mechanism frees up the caller from having to figure out how to proceed when the exceptional condition occurs.

Answer (score 9):

What you have mentioned is not good programming practice. Replacing a `return` statement with `throw` is not acceptable in production-level code, especially with automated testing platforms that generate lists of all exceptions as a way of proving or disproving certain functionality. You have to take into consideration the needs of Software Testers when designing your code. `throw` is simply not interchangeable with `return`. `throw` is used to signal that a program **error** has occurred by some unexpected phenomena. `return` is used to signal method completion. It is common to use `return` to transmit error codes, but return values do not cause the program to be interrupted in the same way as `throw` does. Additionally, `throw` has the power to terminate a program if it is not handled correctly.

Essentially, it is good practice to use `throw` when a significant error is detected within the method, but there should always be a clean return if such an error is not detected. ***Can*** you make that substitution? Maybe, and maybe it will work logically...but it's not good practice and certainly not a popular implementation.

Answer (score 7):

No, `throw` is not a good semantic replacement for `return`. You only want to use `throw` when your code has done something that it should not be doing, not to signify the perfectly valid negative result of a function.

As a general rule, exceptions are meant to signify when something abnormal or unexpected has happened during the execution of your code. Looking at the purpose of your function, the occurrence of no two integers in the passed vector summing to `target` is a very possible result of the function, so that result is not abnormal and thus should not be treated as exceptional.

Answer (score 5):

Your question is language agnostic.

Return and Throw have different purposes.

- Return is for returning a value; while,
- Throw is for throwing an exception; and,

  - An exception should be thrown in truly exceptional conditions.

---

**Bonus Content** (from Steve McConnell’s Code Complete 2)

Here are all the alternatives available to you when you encounter a situation where you cannot return normally:

1. **Return a neutral value** like -1 from a method that’s supposed to return count of something;
2. **Return the closest legal value** like 0 on the digital speedometer of a car when it is going in reverse;
3. **Return same value as previous call** like a temperature reading on a thermometer when you are reading every second and you know that the readings do not differ drastically in such a short interval;
4. **Return the next valid piece of data** like when you are reading rows from a table and a specific row is corrupt;
5. **Set/Return an error status/code/object** found pretty commonly in C++ library calls;
6. **Display a message in an alert box** but be careful to not give out too much that can assist a malicious actor;
7. **Log to a file**;
8. **Throw an exception** like you are pondering upon;
9. **Call a central error handler/routine** if that is how your system is designed;
10. **Shutdown**.

Further, you do not need to pick only one of the above options. You can do a combination like, for example, logging to file **and** displaying a message to the user.

What approach you should take is a question of **Correctness vs Robustness**. Do you want your program to be absolutely correct and shutdown when an erroneous situation is encountered or do you want your program to be robust and continue with execution when at some point it fails to follow the desired path?

Answer (score 5):

Just because the function is throwing as the last call, doesn't mean it is replacing return. It is just the flow of logic.

The question shouldn't be :

> is it a good practice to replace return with throw?

Instead it should be about : **how to define your API and contracts**.

If You want to guarantee to the users of the function that `vector` is never empty, then throwing an exception is a good idea.

If you want to guarantee that your function doesn't throw exceptions instead returns an empty `vector` on certain conditions, then throwing is a bad idea.

In both cases, the user has to know, what actions they have to take to correctly use your function.

Answer (score 3):

I think it is the wrong question asking if ***return*** can be *replaced* by ***throw***. ***return*** and ***throw*** are doing two very different things:

- ***return*** is used to return regular results of a functions.
- ***throw*** is the preferred method to react on error conditions when a result value does not exist.

The alternative reaction on errors could be to return special error code values. This has some disadvantages, e.g.:

- Using a function gets more difficult if you always have to keep error codes etc. in mind.
- The caller might forget to handle the error. When you forget an exception handler, you will get unhandled exception. It is very likely that you will detect this bug.
- The error might be too complex to be expressed by a single error code properly. An exception can be an object containing all the information you need.
- The errors are handled at a well-defined position (the exception handler). This will make your code much clearer than checking the return value for special values after each call.

In your example the answer depends on the semantics of the function:

If an empty vector is an acceptable return value, then you should use ***return*** if no pair is found.

If it is expected that there MUST be matching pairs always, then finding no pair obviously is an error. You should use ***throw*** in this case.