# Program doesn't enter __except block

Tags: c++, exception

I'm trying to realize handling Windows exceptions with the help
of `__try/__except` block.

Problem is that the program never enters `__except` block - only exits incorrectly.

Workspace:
OS: Windows 7 x64; Framework: Embarcadero XE5 C++ Builder;
Application template type: console 64-bit application (for 32-bit works normally!)

Code:

```
void foo()
{
   __try
   {
     int *p = 0;
     fprintf(stderr, "before action");
     *p = 1;
   }
   __except(EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER)
   {
    printf("in __except block\n");
    throw("");
   }
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
 try
 {
   foo();
 }
 catch(...)
 {
   printf("in catch block\n");
 }

 printf("end of main\n");
 return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
before action
```

then incorrect exit

In the second variant I added exception handler this way:

```
LONG WINAPI MyUnhandledExceptionFilter(PEXCEPTION_POINTERS p)
{
  printf("in excepiton filter\n");
  return EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
  AddVectoredExceptionHandler(1, MyVectorExceptionFilter);
  // the same text
  // ...
}
```

After this I got this output:

Output:

```
before action
in excepiton filter
```

then incorrect exit

Why does not the program enters __`except` block?
Is there a way to continue working correctly after entering exception handler?

Comment: Shouldn't you use `__try` if you want to use `__except`?

Comment: Interesting that it even compiles - not a very good MS extension if you can mix and match without the compiler barfing.

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall Have tried - doesn't work :)

Comment: @UKMonkey Could you share some better solutions/practises?

Answer (score 2):

1. *p = 1; won't throw... what you want is "throw std::Exception()"
2. throwing is relatively expensive [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1897940/in-what-ways-do-c-exceptions-slow-down-code-when-there-are-no-exceptions-thown), so try{ try{ } catch {throw} } catch{} is bad.  just the one try catch is needed
3. (opinion) stick with portable things - try catch.  MS added this by the looks so that they could have finally, like java does.  If you use __try __catch you'll start using these and when you have to write something on Linux you'll wonder why it's not compiling

> Is there a way to continue working correctly after entering exception handler?

Depends on the exception, and what it means to your program.  The only suggestion is to follow the naming - Exceptions are exceptional. It could be that reading would block, in which case you can just sit around and wait for more - or it could be that a dll couldn't be loaded and it was needed by your application - in which case no, you can't recover.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Exceptions caused by code like mine can't be caught by standard try/catch block (please, correct me but I proved it experimentally). About aim of catching: in case of critical error I want only to post my message to user and close app correctly. But in exception handler after printf it exits incorrectly.

Comment: "Exceptions caused by code like mine can't be caught by standard try/catch block "  -  see my point (1).   
Regarding your other part, we don't know what MyVectorExceptionFilter is; is there a typo in the question?

Comment: I would suggest you examine https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681411(v=vs.85).aspx a little more closely

Answer (score 2):

You must be consistent. You can use the C++ `try` and `catch` to catch C++ exceptions, or you can use the Microsoft Structured Exception Handling to catch low level errors with **`__try`**, `__except` and eventually `__finally`.

In your example, you never enter the exception handler because the guarded block was incorrectly introduced with the C++ keyword `try`.

Just replacing the offending `try` with `__try` allows the exception handler to be correctly calles.

Comment: Thanks for answer! I've already tried replacing `try` with `__try` - feature remains. Question is corrected.

Comment: @Sas: I can no longer reproduce. The code currently in the question gives correctly `before actionin __except block
in catch block
end of main` in my old VS2008 32 bits (I use `#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>` as headers) both in UNICODE and MBCS mode. The only weird thing is that you throw a C string which could cause problem. What happens if you throw an int or a C++ string?